# React, passing a value from parent to two different children

Tags: reactjs, react-native, foreach

Passing a value from parent component. It is working for Nav component but it is not working for TextComponent component. Nested return and loop will not allow passing the value?

```
<div className="container">
            {                   
                currentpage.map((rows, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={i} className="row">               
                            <Nav editModeState={this.state.editModeState} /> //This editModeState is working fine.

                            {rows.row.map(function (component, i) { 

                                return <div className="col-lg-4">                                       
                                    <div key={i} className="card" key={i}>
                                      <div className="card-body">                                            
                                            <TextComponent
                                            componentFromParent = {component}
                                            editModeState={this.state.editModeState} //The value is not passing, but it is working for <Nav editModeState={this.state.editModeState} /> component
                                            />  
                                      </div>
                                    </div>      
                                </div>
                            })}
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
            </div>
```

**Constructor**

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    editModeState: ""
  }
}
fromnaveditor(params) {
  this.setState({
    editModeState: params
  })
}
```

**ERROR**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: It says TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined. 

 constructor(){
   super();
   this.state= {
     editModeState : ""
   }
 }

 fromnaveditor(params) {
   this.setState({
     editModeState : params
   })
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with function binding here. `this is not bind properly to map function`.
There are 2 ways to fix the problem:

#### Use fat arrow syntax (=>)

Use fat arrow function (the way it is used here `currentpage.map((rows, i) => {`) to fix the error

```
{rows.row.map((component, i) => { /* Your code here */ })}
```

---

#### Provide this to map function

The map function takes the second argument `this`. So the code will be modified to:

```
{rows.row.map(function(component, i) { /* Your code here */ }, this)}
```